# Replacing string (comma-separated values) using regexp

Tags: regex

How to replace a string (comma-separated values) using regular expression?

Example:

```
The,quick,fox,jumped
```

To:

```
s.The,s.quick,s.fox,s.jumped
```

Comment: Can the values contain double-quotes? Can they contain commas if in double-quotes? Can there be blank values?

Comment: no, the values do not contain double-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the beginning of the line or a comma, and replace that with itself plus the new text. With sed:

```
$ echo "The,quick,fox,jumped" | sed 's/\(^\|,\)/&s./g'
s.The,s.quick,s.fox,s.jumped
```

Another approach is to split the string using comma as the separator, add the the text to each element of the resulting list, then join again with a comma. With perl, we can have the terse one-liner:

```
echo "The,quick,fox,jumped" | perl -F, -ane 'print join ",", map {"s.$_"} @F'
```

Comment: With vanilla sed, `\(` and `\)` are grouping/capturing parentheses, and `\|` is regex alternation. `\(^\|,\)` will thus match either `^` (the start of the string) or a comma. In the replacement part `&` is replaced by whatever text the pattern matched (either the empty string at the beginning of the string or a comma).

Comment: In hindsight, the parentheses are not required, so it's slightly simpler: `sed 's/^\|,/&s./g'`